# Automatic Detection of mass storage/external drive in Android

Tags: android, detection

Is it possible or is there a way in Android v2.2+ to detect if there is a mass storage, external drive or micro SD inserted in the device?

My objective is, I want to create an app that will be invoked once an external storage like micro SD is inserted in the device?

I want to know if:
1) Is there a standard intent broadcasted once an SD is mounted in the device?
2) Do I have to deal with it in the native driver layer to achieve this?

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about, create your own service that will listen for mounting of the sdcard, start your service at boot up, and whenever there is true value returned from the test for storage run your app. Check regularly for a some amount of time (not good idea, though) Note: You may end up with ARN/service crash.

Comment: That's a great suggestion on how not to do it, actually.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a standard intent broadcast, you are probably looking for the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` broadcast.

> **ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED**
>
> Since: API Level 1
>   Broadcast Action: External media is present and
>   mounted at its mount point. The path to the mount point for the
>   removed media is contained in the Intent.mData field. The Intent
>   contains an extra with name "read-only" and Boolean value to indicate
>   if the media was mounted read only.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)